# Animation repeats after keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a svg, css animation and added some jquery keyboard events. 
Everytime when I hit the key the animation starts again and again.

Is there any way to only play the animation once the page is loaded?

also the swipe event doesn't work anymore (i tested it with an image before)

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            $(".arrow_down").animate({
                top:"+=20px",
                opacity:"0"
            });
            $(".button").animate({
                opacity:"1"
            });
        }
          if (e.keyCode === 37) {     
            $(".arrow_down").effect("bounce",{times:3}, 500 );
        }
         if (e.keyCode === 39) {     
            $(".arrow_down").effect("bounce",{times:3}, 500 );
        }
         if (e.keyCode === 38) {     
            $(".arrow_down").effect("bounce",{times:3}, 500 );
        }
    });
    $(".arrow_down").swipe({
        swipeDown:function(){
            $(".arrow_down svg").animate({top:"+=5%", opacity:"0"});
            $(".button").animate({opacity:"1"});
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9KwLW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay; I figured it out.
It's maybe not the most elegant soloution, but I can't find a better one.

So I changed the class with the animation from "line" to "animline". Then after 700ms I search all items with class "line" and remove their class "animline" - I can't use jQuery for that, because jQuery can't search elements within SVG just now without any plugins, so why not to use some plain JavaScript.

**See the fiddle:**    http://jsfiddle.net/9KwLW/2/

JS:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
       lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');
        for (i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
             lines[i].classList.remove("animline");   
        }
    },700);
```

CSS:

```
.animline {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
 -moz-animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
 -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

HTML:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="7px" height="193px" viewBox="0 0 7 193" enable-background="new 0 0 7 193" xml:space="preserve"><line class="line animline" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="3.5" y1="0" x2="3.5" y2="193"/>
</svg>

<svg class="arrow_head" version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"width="63.25px" height="36.75px" viewBox="0 0 63.25 36.75" enable-background="new 0 0 63.25 36.75" xml:space="preserve"><polyline class="line animline" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="60.5,2.686 31.688,30.509 2.875,2.686 "/></svg>
```

Comment: You're welcome... You also may try `$('...').on('swipe',function(){ ... })` instead of `$('...').swipe(function(){ ... });`.

Answer (score 1):

I may have a better solution for you:

Set the default `stroke-dashoffset` to `1` for `.line` and then set a `from` element to your `dash` animation that sets the `stroke-dashoffset` to `1000` at the beginning of the animation.

```
from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
```

Now if you remove the `animation` attribute to `.line`, the arrow will be shown and no more animation will be triggered.

```
$(".line").css("-webkit-animation", "none").css("-moz-animation", "none");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9KwLW/3/